# Found class io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf, but interface was expected

Tags: java

I have tried several versions of netty-all but it doesnt seem to work. Any idea where I am going wrong ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf, but interface was expected
    at org.vertx.java.core.buffer.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:72)
    at org.vertx.java.core.eventbus.impl.DefaultEventBus.<clinit>(DefaultEventBus.java:58)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultVertx.<init>(DefaultVertx.java:73)
    at org.vertx.java.core.impl.DefaultVertxFactory.createVertx(DefaultVertxFactory.java:29)
    at org.vertx.java.core.VertxFactory.newVertx(VertxFactory.java:33)
    at osiam.CreateUser.main(CreateUser.java:21)
```

Comment: It is a runtime exception telling you that the code found at runtime is fundamentally different from the code that was provided at compile time.

Comment: any suggestions about the approach I can take to overcome this ?

Comment: @RakeshRangappa Compile it with the same version of netty as the one you run with.

Comment: What is the version of the vertx you use?